# Unable to load "path" with "stringWithFormat" objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

i have this method that load html file from my application into UIWebView.
the issue is that this file name change from time to time - and i cant get it to work.
this is my code:

```
    NSString *path;
    NSBundle *thisBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    path = [thisBundle pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_file",MyFileNameString] ofType:@"htm"];

// make a file: URL out of the path
    NSURL *instructionsURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    [ProfileHtml loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:instructionsURL]];
```

and i get this problem: `[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter.`

when i use it for example in this way its work:

```
NSString *path;
NSBundle *thisBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
path = [thisBundle pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_file",@"amir"] ofType:@"htm"];

// make a file: URL out of the path
NSURL *instructionsURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
[ProfileHtml loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:instructionsURL]];
```

what should i do to fix it ?
Thanks !

////////// update

this is the whole method:
hope you can help me.

```
   NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSString *zodiacProfile = [defaults valueForKey:@"zodiacProfile"];    

        NSLog(@"zodiacProfile: %@",zodiacProfile);
        [zodiacWallpaper setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Wallpaper_%@",zodiacProfile]]];
        zodiacTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"About %@",zodiacProfile];

        NSString *path;
        NSBundle *thisBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
        path = [thisBundle pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@HTM",zodiacProfile] ofType:@"htm"];

        NSURL *instructionsURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

        NSLog(@"zodiac: %@",zodiacProfile);
        NSLog(@"path: %@",path);
        NSLog(@"url: %@",instructionsURL);

        [ProfileHtml loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:instructionsURL]];
```

Comment: What is the content of `MyFileNameString` then?  If that's the only difference between working and not-working, then that's the problem.

Comment: In your first example are you sure that `MyFileNameString` is set to the value you think it is?  And are you sure a file with that name exists in your bundle?

Comment: Are you sure that all htm files have been added to the correct target before you build the app (Copy Files build phase) ?

Comment: I'd say you should test the results of `pathForResource` and `fileURLWithPath` for nil.

Comment: the path become nil when im using it like the first example.. thats the problem but how should i fix it ?

Comment: show us how do you assign `MyFileNameString` and your problem will be solved

Comment: i just add it to the message. hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was that i want in focus and forgot to add the html files into my project.
So to all of you who will need this code sometime in the future - its working perfect.

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSString *zodiacProfile = [defaults valueForKey:@"zodiacProfile"];

```
    NSLog(@"zodiacProfile: %@",zodiacProfile);
    [zodiacWallpaper setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Wallpaper_%@",zodiacProfile]]];
    zodiacTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"About %@",zodiacProfile];

    NSString *path;
    NSBundle *thisBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    path = [thisBundle pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@HTM",zodiacProfile] ofType:@"htm"];

    NSURL *instructionsURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    NSLog(@"zodiac: %@",zodiacProfile);
    NSLog(@"path: %@",path);
    NSLog(@"url: %@",instructionsURL);

    [ProfileHtml loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:instructionsURL]];
```